# react.DOM provider syntax error

Tags: react-redux

I have this problem :

> ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
>          Module build failed : SyntaxError: Unexpected token(20:2)

project adress : https://github.com/mresulakyuz/React-Redux-Router-Webpack.git

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
    const history = createBrowserHistory();

    import Sstore from './store/configureStore.js';
    import { loadMovies } from './actions/movieActions.js';
    import App from './App.js';


    const store = Sstore;

    store.dispatch(loadMovies());


    ReactDOM.render(

      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?